# Variadic expansion to access multi-dimensional std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, variadic-templates, pack-expansion

Suppose the following multi_array structure:

```cpp
template <typename type, std::size_t... sizes>
struct multi_array
{
  using storage_type    = typename storage_type<type, sizes...>::type;
  using value_type      = type;
  using size_type       = std::array<std::size_t   , sizeof...(sizes)>;
  using difference_type = std::array<std::ptrdiff_t, sizeof...(sizes)>;
  using reference       = value_type&;
  using const_reference = const value_type&;
  // ...

  storage_type data_  {};
  size_type    sizes_ {sizes...};
}

// Example usage: 
// multi_array<float, 3, 4, 5> three_dimensional_float_array;
// storage_type will be std::array<std::array<std::array<float, 5>, 4>, 3>
// size_type    will be std::array<std::size_t, 3>
```

where:

```cpp
// Helpers to create a std::array<std::array<...>> from a pack expansion.
template <typename  type,                   std::size_t... sizes>
struct storage_type;
template <typename _type, std::size_t size, std::size_t... sizes>
struct storage_type<_type, size, sizes...>
{
  using type = std::array<typename storage_type<_type, sizes...>::type, size>;
};
template <typename _type>
struct storage_type<_type>
{
  using type = _type;
};
```

I am now trying to implement the .at() function:

```cpp
  [[nodiscard]]
  constexpr reference       at   (const size_type& position)
  {
    // This has to be:
    // data_[position[0]][position[1]][position[2]]...;
  }
```

Fold expressions do not work in this case so a recursive solution is necessary.

I think this is the way, but can't seem to come up with the right answer:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]]
constexpr reference at(const size_type& position)
{
  return access_type<value_type, sizeof...(sizes)>::at(data_, position);
}

template <typename type, std::size_t size, std::size_t index = 0>
struct access_type
{
  template <typename array_type>
  auto at (const array_type& array, const std::array<std::size_t, size>& position, type& current) // Problem: Reference is not a type& for intermediates.
  {
    if constexpr (index == 0)
      current = &array;

    if constexpr (index + 1 != size)
    {
      return access_type::at<type, size, index + 1>(array, position, current);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: FYI, `multi_array` doesn't actually meet the requirements of being container, since `size_type` needs to be an unsigned integer type and `difference_type` needs to be a signed integer type. See [tab:container.req] from the standard, or [Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) on cppreference

Comment: `position` is a reference to a single, lonely `size_type`.  `position[0]` does not compute.

Comment: `position` is a `std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(sizes)>`

Comment: It would probably be much, much simpler to define `multi_array` as a wrapper around a single `std::array` with an `operator[]` that provides multidimensional indexing rather than having actual nested arrays. You'd also get all the required container type aliases for free that way.

Comment: @Brian the standard would have to be modified if a std::multi_array is ever considered.

Answer to second comment: That would require arithmetic operations on each .at() operation compared to N reads when indexing into a std::array<std::array<...>>. It would be easier to write yes, and less efficient.

Comment: @demiralp Why? It's perfectly possible to create a standard-compliant multidimensional array container. You just can't co-opt the standard machinery to do things other than what they were designed to do.

Comment: How would you index into a multidimensional array with only a std::size_t without defeating the purpose of a multidimensional array?

Comment: @demiralp Comments aren't the place for extended discussion. If you want, we can discuss this further in a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: In the case of a multi_vector, having a single std::vector and indexing into it by mapping an N dimensional index to 1D index is necessary in order to keep it contiguous. However as in multi_array, when size is known at compile time, and std::array of std::array of ... is guaranteed contiguity, this is not the most efficient option.
Sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240060/discussion-between-demiralp-and-brian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <size_t level, size_t max_level>
struct Access {
  template<typename Store>
  static reference At(Store& store, const size_type& position) {
    return Access<level + 1, max_level>::At(
        store[position[level]], position);
  }
};

template <size_t level>
struct Access<level, level> {
  template<typename Store>
  static reference At(Store& store, const size_type&) {
    return store;
  }
};


reference at(const size_type& position)
{
  return Access<0, sizeof...(sizes)>::At(data_, position);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this also gives a lot of insight on how to implement the other members analogous to std::array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

```
namespace _details
{
    template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
    OutputIt partial_product(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt output)
    { *output++ = 1; return partial_sum(first, last, output, std::multiplies<>{}); }

    // cache-friendly:
    // neighbor objects within the right-most coordinate are neighbors in memory
    template<class TDim, class TCoord>
    auto coordinates_to_index(TDim const& dimensions, TCoord const& coords)
    {
        std::array<std::size_t, dimensions.size()> dimension_product;
        using std::crbegin, std::crend, std::prev;
        partial_product(crbegin(dimensions), prev(crend(dimensions)), begin(dimension_product));
        return std::inner_product(cbegin(dimension_product), cend(dimension_product), crbegin(coords), 0);
    }
}
```

It transforms tuple `(x,y,z,...)` into 1-D index `x*N + y*K + ...`, where `N`, `K`, ... are chosen accordingly to the total container dimensions.

And used in my own multi-dimension cache-friendly container:

```
    /**
     * @brief Returns a reference to the element at coordinates.
     * @param coordinates Coordinates of the element to return
     *
     * No bounds checking is performed; if @c coordinates are outside od
     * the matrix dimensions, the behavior is undefined.
     */
    template<class... Args>
    T const& operator()(Args... coordinates) const
    { return _data[_details::coordinates_to_index(dimensions, std::array{coordinates...})]; }
```

Source : [yscialom/matrix/matrix.hpp on my GitHub](https://github.com/yscialom/matrix/blob/develop/src/include/matrix.hpp#L21) (PR welcomed)